# How can I show the picture from my gmail into the Navigation view of my app?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide, google-authentication

I am trying to use the Glide library, for which I added the dependencies:

> https://github.com/bumptech/glide

.
My name and email are shown successfully, but my photo is not.
Here is the snippet of code:

```
//controls
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    tvUserName = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvGoogleName);
    tvEmail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    imgProfile = headerView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);

    //google
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if(acct != null){
        String userName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String email = acct.getEmail();
        Uri photo = acct.getPhotoUrl();

        if(photo != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "photo is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // true
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "photo is  null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        tvUserName.setText(userName);
        tvEmail.setText(email);

        Glide.with(this).load(String.valueOf(photo)).into(imgProfile);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getPhotoUrl%28%29)

```
public Uri getPhotoUrl ()
```

Returns the photo url of the signed in user if the user has a profile picture and you built your configuration either starting from new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)} or with GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestProfile() configured; null otherwise. **Not guaranteed to be present for all users, even when configured.**

Can you verify whether you are getting a valid URL or not from getPhotoUrl

Comment: It worked as I reinstalled the app. I added the picture on my account after I already signed in. Thank you for your answer :)